# Create Object of class in same package

Tags: java, package, access-specifier

I created a class HT17

```
package useFul;
class HT17 
{
    void show() 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

And i tried accessing it from another class from same package

```
package useFul;
class HT18
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HT17 h =new HT17();
        h.show();
    }
}
```

But i am getting error: Cannot find symbol HT17
Yes, They are in same directory i.e useFul
A solution would be helpful!

Comment: Are you sure you have compiled both of the classes?

Comment: Having the same package name and being the same package is not always the same. Can you show your project tree? Also: are you sure you compiled HT17 before you tried to run HT18/ ?

Comment: Make your classes public, i.e. "public class HT17"

Comment: make you `HT18` class public

Comment: How are you compiling these?

Comment: @Rustam, Thomas Stets: Public is irrelevant, they are in the same package.

Comment: @kocko I am having trouble compiling the HT18 class

Comment: @Stultuske Yes HT17 compiles just fine.

Comment: @immibis I am comiling this using cmd

Comment: @Rafiq I am not using an IDE just a text editor and cmd to compile and run

Comment: @hthakkar8 ... and what are you typing in cmd?

Comment: @hthakkar8 create a folder named useFul and copy the classes there, then cmd to compile and run

Comment: @immibis javac HT18.java

Comment: @Rafiq I have already created the folder useFul but the problem is that i cannot compile HT18 in useFul but if i move it one directory back it compiles without errors, its currently in D:\Hardik\useFul where it doesnt complie but it compiles in  D:\Hardik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using `javac <file name>` this will create the class file in the same folder even though you have a package defined.

So you've to use `javac -d .` option this will create proper folder structure for the classes. Try the following.

```
$ javac HT17.java -d .
$ javac HT18.java -d .
$ java useFul.HT18
```

The `-d` is used to mention where to create the compiled classes with proper folder structure using package. in the example `.` is used, means use the current directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @karthikeyan , Can i do it without using -d?

Comment: You can but you have to create a folder named useful and copy the classes there. -d does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

At first create a folder named useFul and copy the classes there, then cmd to compile and run. cmd command:

```
 javac useFul/HT18.java
 java useFul/HT18
```